# Not able to create the combo chart through pptxgenjs

Tags: pptxgenjs, combo-chart

I am trying to create the combo chart of line and area,
since addChart expecting 3 arguments, I am not able to overide the 2 argument for combo chart hence I am sending data only. but not able to create the ppt.
Kindly check and update.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Do you have any update on this?